# how to import a.py not a folder

Tags: python, import

```
zjm_code
    |-----a.py
    |-----a
          |----- __init__.py
    |-----b.py
```

in a.py is :

```
c='ccc'
```

in b.py is :

```
import a

print dir(a)
```

when i execute b.py ,it show (it import 'a' folder):

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__path__']
```

and when i **delete** a folder, it show ,(it import a.py):

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', 'c']
```

so my question is :

how to import a.py  via not delete a folder

thanks

**updated**

i use imp.load_source, so in b.py is :

```
import imp,os
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.join('aaa.py'))
ok=imp.load_source('*',path)
print ok.c
```

it is ok now ,and print 'ccc'

and

how to show 'ccc' via  "print c"  **not** via "print ok.c"  ???

thanks

**updated2**

it is ok now :

```
imp.load_source('anyname',path)

from anyname import *
print c
```

it show 'ccc'

**updated3**

it is also ok:

```
import imp,os
imp.load_source('anyname','aaa.py')
from anyname import *
print c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imp.load_module` - there you can specify the file directory, overriding the behaviour of import.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the folder to a different name. A folder with the same name takes precedence.

Comment: a *package* with the same name takes precedence.